# Ember.js Routing: match end of url

Tags: javascript, url-routing, ember.js

I need to match a path into an URL. The path has to be the end of the URL after a given pattern, but I can't do it.
Ember.js always end it's matching to the next slash.

```js
var router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: 'history',
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/'

            repo: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/:repo_id',

                index: Ember.Route.extend({
                    route: '/'
                }),

                files: Ember.Route.extend({
                    route: '/files',

                    index: Ember.Route.extend({
                        route: '/'
                    }),

                    sub: Ember.Route.extend({
                        route: '/:path'
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
});
```

With this router:

- `/myrepo/files/` will match `root.repo.files.index`
- `/myrepo/files/README` will match `root.repo.files.sub` with `path=README`
- `/myrepo/files/folder/README` will match `root.repo.files.sub` and will reroute me to `/myrepo/files/folder/` because `path=folder` instead of `path=folder/README`

How can I to have sub route match the end of URL with `:path` even when there is slash into it or not ?

Answer (score 3):

This functionality has been [committed](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/12f65b76014430a828af70accd0d91f5666565a9) to the Ember.js repository's [master](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js) branch. It is not in the `1.0.0-pre2` build, so until a new version is released you will need to either [build Ember.js yourself](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js#building-emberjs) or find a prebuilt version.

## Basic Usage

Instead of prefixing your dynamic segment with a colon `:`, use an asterisk `*`. Your route will use a syntax similar to:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/:repo_id/files/*path'
});
```

The path segment will be available just as if it were a normal dynamic property. However, it will include anything after `files/` in the URL, including slashes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an opened issue on Ember.js Github Tracker:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1451