# Ember Router dynamic segment globbing

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router, glob

I'm looking for a way to use [Rails-routes-like globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) in Ember.Router (1.0pre).
My goal is to match a path as a dynamic segment.

I'd like to have a route like that (CoffeeScript) :

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend
    location: 'hash'
    enableLogging: true
    root: Ember.Route.extend
        myRoute: Ember.Route.extend
            route: '/:path*'
            connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
                { ... something here ... }
```

Unfortunately, Ember._RouteMatcher does not seem to support that kind of syntax (the trailing asterisk in the route), so I'm unable to create a route that would match a dynamic segment like '/long/path/to/something'.

Has anyone ever managed to do that (or found some kind of workaround) ?

Comment: My question is close to [NoirBizarre's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151423/ember-js-routing-match-end-of-url). Has anyone else tried to do that ?

Comment: The 10th item in the [changelog for 1.0.0-pre.2](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG) (released Oct 25th):
"Adds support for globbed routes".  Haven't tried it or seen anything else about it.

Comment: Yep, this commit shold have fixed the problem : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/9e8cf4579e177f66c4986efd48fa6fdeb5b73ff1#packages/ember-routing/lib Unfortunately, I did not have time to test it, yet.